# How do I prevent elements from trasitioning in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

hope you are safe during the pandemics.

I'd like to have a fixed header on the screen while transitioning from a screen to another. My code is as follows:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

# Window.fullscreen = True
Window.size = (800, 480)
Window.borderless = "1"
Window.clearcolor = (0.976470588235, 0.976470588235, 0.976470588235, 1)


class Launch(App):
    def build(self):
        kv_file = Builder.load_file("app.kv")
        return kv_file


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Launch().run()
```

and my .kv file,

```
<Button>:
    size_hint: 0.325, 0.3125

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main_window"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            text: "Lorem Ipsum"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": (480-50)/480}
            size_hint: 1, 50/480

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.14583375, "y": 0.50694375}
            text: "OP1"

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.14583375, "y": 0.09722292}
            text: "OP2"

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.52916625, "y": 0.50694375}
            text: "OP3"

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.52916625, "y": 0.09722292}
            text: "OP4"

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.88958375, "y":0.38616458}
            size_hint: 0.075, 0.144
            text: "->"
            on_press:
                app.root.current = "second_window"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second_window"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            text: "Lorem Ipsum"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": (480-50)/480}
            size_hint: 1, 50/480

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.14583375, "y": 0.50694375}
            text: "OP1"

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.14583375, "y": 0.09722292}
            text: "OP2"

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.52916625, "y": 0.50694375}
            text: "OP3"

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.52916625, "y": 0.09722292}
            text: "OP4"

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.03541625, "y": 0.38616458}
            size_hint: 0.075, 0.144
            text: "<-"
            on_press:
                app.root.current = "main_window"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

The way it is, the Label that is on top of the screen changes to itself during the transition and my goal is to make it static as the rest of the screen transits left/right. What can be done to pin this label header?

Comment: Put the Label and ScreenManager both inside some container class, then when you change screens the ScreenManager will update but the Label won't be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As inclement already mentioned you have to make a container class and put your Label (header) and the ScreenManager inside 
app.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class Launch(App):
    def build(self):
        kv_file = Builder.load_file("app.kv")
        return kv_file

class MainWindow(FloatLayout):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Launch().run()
```

app.kv

```
<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    id: first_window
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: my_button
            text:"Hi"
            on_release: app.root.manager.current = 'second'
<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second'
    id: second_window
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:"Bye"
            on_release: app.root.manager.current = 'first'


MainWindow:
    manager: manager
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Header'
        ScreenManager:
            id: manager
            FirstScreen:
            SecondScreen:
```

Comment: WOOW, thats precise! Thank you!!